# Stumped on Nested Multi-Table MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, subquery

I'm trying to do a rather complicated (to me) nested query.  My data is in three tables:

1. tblsite - fields siteid (key), sitename
2. tblroom - fields
   roomid (key)
   roomsite   (This defines which site the room is at, from siteid)
3. tblcomputer - fields
   computerid (key)
   computerroom   (This defines which room the computer is in)

So I want to run a query that lists three things - the name of the site, the count of the rooms in the site, and the count of the computers at that site.

At present, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT siteid, sitename, (SELECT Count(*) FROM tblroom WHERE roomsite LIKE siteid) as     
siteroomcount, .....
```

The ..... indicates where the subquery for the computer count needs to go.  It needs to somehow run a subquery for each room at the site, and a secondary subquery to count the computers in each room for that site.  I hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance!

-Scott Davis

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you an example, so I think you can extrapolate to adequate to your situation

let's say we have something like this

```
create table site (sid int);
create table room (rid int, sid int);
create table comp (cid int, rid int);

insert into site values (1);
insert into site values (2);
insert into site values (3);
insert into room values (33,1);
insert into room values (44,1);
insert into room values (55,2);
insert into comp values (666,33);
insert into comp values (777,33);
insert into comp values (888,44);
insert into comp values (999,55);
```

then this query

```
SELECT s.sid,
       Count(DISTINCT( r.rid )),
       Count(DISTINCT( c.cid ))
FROM   site s
left outer join room r on s.sid = r.sid
left outer join comp c on r.rid = c.rid
GROUP  BY s.sid
```

will give you

```
SID     COUNT(DISTINCT(R.RID))  COUNT(DISTINCT(C.CID))
1       2                       3
2       1                       1
3       0                       0
```

Comment: That query does seem to work somewhat - however, some of my sites currently don't have any computers or rooms assigned to them, and instead of returning a count of zero, it just doesn't list the site at all.  Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: Thank you - this worked!  And since we've had success so far, can I ask for one more thing?  Within the ROOM table there is a column called type.  Type 1 is a computer lab, and type 2 is a laptop cart.  How could I add two more count statements that also count DISTINCT from the room table, but only those rooms that have a specific type?  Thanks a bunch for your help, Leo!

Comment: @ScottDavis, you're changing the question :-)

Comment: You're right, I am.  But I still have no idea how to do it, and it seems like you are extremely skilled at MySQL, and thus I chose to ask.  I promise this will be the last addition to my original question.